# If condition in for loop messing up pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, if-statement

I am trying to mutate a data frame in a for loop based on an if condition.

```
import pandas as pd
#read the read.csv file

def write_csv(email, info):
    df1 = pd.read_csv('/Users/thavas/Downloads/write.csv')
    #iterate over df1 and look for email
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        print(index)
        if row['Email 1'] == email:
            #change the value of column 8 to "hello"
            df1.loc[index,'Email 2'] = "hello"
        df1.to_csv('/Users/thavas/Downloads/out.csv')
            

                
def read_csv():
    #iterate over rows in dataframe
    df = pd.read_csv('/Users/thavas/Downloads/read.csv')
    for index,rows in df.iterrows():
        email = rows['Email']
        #if email available
        if email != 'nan':
            #get column 8,9,10,11 of rows
            info = rows[8:17]
            write_csv(email, info)
        
        else:
            print("Users", rows['Contact'], "has no email")
            
read_csv()
```

However I am running into an error where with the if statements, no data is being added to the csv file.

Doing some debugging, I realized that by putting print statements inside the if statements I get many outputs. So getting in the if statements is not a problem.

Additionally, after taking out all the if statements, I see outputs into my csv file.
What could be going wrong?

**UPDATE**
I noticed that only the last loop of data is being read and updated to my out file.

What does this mean?

Comment: Are you sure nan values ​​are kept as strings ? did you try `if email != np.nan:` instead of `if email != 'nan':`

Comment: good idea but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Clegane Notice that np.nan != np.nan. NaNs are strange creatures...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified the question to make my explanation easier. I've used only three columns in `read.csv` (`eid`, `name`, and `email`) and `write.csv` has (`email1`, and `email2`).

The goal is to create `out.csv` which is a copy of `write.csv` with the email2 field filled up for all emails that exist in `read.csv`.

The following code matches most of your logic, and I'll use it to highlight some issues.

```
import pandas as pd

# printing just so you can see the structure explained above
rdf = pd.read_csv('./read.csv')
wdf = pd.read_csv('./write.csv')

print("read.csv")
print(rdf)

print("write.csv")
print(wdf)


def write_csv(email):
    df1 = pd.read_csv('./write.csv')
    #iterate over df1 and look for email
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        if row['email1'] == email:
            #change the value of column 8 to "hello"
            df1.loc[index,'email2'] = "hello"
        df1.to_csv('./out.csv')           # <---- Reference 2
        #              ^ Reference 3

def read_csv():
    #iterate over rows in dataframe
    df = pd.read_csv('./read.csv')
    for index,rows in df.iterrows():
        email = rows['email']
        #if email available
        if email != 'nan': # <-- Reference 1
            write_csv(email) # <-- Reference 4

read_csv()
```

And the output

```
(stackoverflow) /tmp $ python test.py

read.csv
   eid    name                   email
0    1     Tom   tom@stackoverflow.com
1    2   Alice
2    3     Bob   bob@stackoverflow.com
3    4     Tim

write.csv
                  email1           email2
0  tom@stackoverflow.com   email2-unknown
1  bob@stackoverflow.com   email2-unknown

(stackoverflow) /tmp $ cat out.csv
,email1,email2
0,tom@stackoverflow.com, email2-unknown
1,bob@stackoverflow.com, email2-unknown
```

Reference 1:

This really depends on your csv file and what you expect to find there. If empty emails are actually represented in your file as 'nan' then this seems fine. However, in my case the file actually has nothing (`''`) for missing emails. So pandas makes them `NaN`. However, you can't compare it directly with `'nan'`.

Possible solutions

1. `if str(email) == 'nan'` as str(nan) is `'nan'`
2. `if isinstance(email, float) and np.isnan(email)` where `np.isnan` is a function from numpy but that only works on floats. Giving it a string will cause an error.
3. Convert the entire column to string in the beginning and then iterate over the rows. `pd.read_csv('./read.csv').astype({'email':'str'})`. You can then just compare `email == 'nan'` like before.
4. Only iterate over non-nan values. i.e. `for index, rows in df[~df.email.isna()].iterrows()` where `df.email.isna()` checks if something is NaN and the `~` negates that. So you get all rows where email is not NaN.

With this, you are guaranteed that `write_csv` will be called correctly.

Reference 2:

Writing `out.csv` on every iteration is costly. If `write.csv` has a 1000 rows, you'll be writing `out.csv` a 1000 times. Instead, you'll want to write `out.csv` only once outside the for loop.

Reference 3 and 4:

When you find a non-empty email from `read.csv`, `write_csv` is called for a specific email. For example, lets take the first row, `tom@stackoverflow.com`. So now `write_csv` reads `write.csv`, modifies all instances where email is `tom...` and then writes it to `out.csv`.

Except that when it moves to the next non-empty email, `bob...`, you again read from `write.csv` which overwrites `out.csv`. `write.csv` did not have the changes you made for `tom`. This explains why you'll only see the last email.

Possible solutions:

1. A quick fix is to first copy `write.csv` to `out.csv` (before `read_csv` is called) and modify the `write_csv` to always read `out.csv` and write to `out.csv` too.

Putting it all together:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rdf = pd.read_csv('./read.csv')
wdf = pd.read_csv('./write.csv')

print("read.csv")
print(rdf)

print("write.csv")
print(wdf)


def write_csv(email):
    df1 = pd.read_csv('./out.csv') # read from out
    #iterate over df1 and look for email
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        if row['email1'] == email:
            #change the value of column 8 to "hello"
            df1.loc[index,'email2'] = "hello"

    # outside for loop
    # write to out, so next call with different email also persists
    df1.to_csv('./out.csv') 

def read_csv():
    #iterate over rows in dataframe
    df = pd.read_csv('./read.csv')
    # iterate over rows with non-nan emails
    for index,rows in df[~df.email.isna()].iterrows():
        # I've removed the info part with other columns but you get the idea...
        email = rows['email']
        write_csv(email)

import shutil
shutil.copyfile('./write.csv', './out.csv') # first copy to out
read_csv()
```

The above will give you a working solution but is still quite inefficient since you are writing `out.csv` for every single email that exists.

Instead, think about creating `out.csv` by merging/joining the dataframes from `read.csv` and `write.csv`. Here are some links to the docs
[merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and
[join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html).
Maybe also look at some examples from stackoverflow questions on pandas joins and merges.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the really detailed answer. I will make sure to add the bounty in 22 hours Aas it worked. However, I found a way to just add the read emails into a list. Then use the write function to work on this list. Finishes in 1.2 seconds wheras the previous was 1 min. Thank you though!